# How to get a Pi4 to Boot into lxde-pi Desktop Environment?

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, lxde

This on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1, running Buster originally installed as a Stage 4 - Normal Raspbian image.

https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen

This Pi is headless. RealVNC is enabled via raspi-config.

When I log in to this Pi via VNC the desktop that I see is solid blue (sometimes black) and contains no menu bar or desktop icons. A menu can be enabled by right clicking the desktop. Many menu items do not work at all.

To get a functional desktop I can start a terminal session within the VNC session and enter: `startlxde-pi &`

That instantly enables the familiar Buster desktop with a menu bar, desktop icons and Burmese temple wallpaper.

Unfortunately, that doesn't survive a reboot.

**So, the question is: What do I need to do to establish a persistent lxde-pi DE that starts at boot?**

====================

What follows are various configuration options and files that might be useful in helping me figure this out:

```
Raspberry Pi Software Configuration Tool (raspi-config) 

B1 Console           Text console, requiring user to login        
B2 Console Autologin Text console, automatically logged in as 'pi' user    
B3 Desktop           Desktop GUI, requiring user to login 
B4 Desktop Autologin Desktop GUI, automatically logged [selected]
```

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative x-session-manager (providing /usr/bin/x-session-manager).

  Selection    Path                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/startlxde-pi      90        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/lxsession         49        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/openbox-session   40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/startlxde         50        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/startlxde-pi      90        manual mode

$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-window-manager
There is only one alternative in link group x-window-manager (providing /usr/bin/x-window-manager): /usr/bin/openbox
Nothing to configure.

$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
There is only one alternative in link group x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator): /usr/bin/lxterminal
Nothing to configure.
```

```
pi@raspmountain:/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi $ cat autostart
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

There is no user autostart file

Interesting lines from .xsession-errors

```
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=openbox
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=openbox
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDMSESSION=openbox
Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "/var/lib/openbox/debian-menu.xml"
```

Those same lines and more from a different but identical Pi that does have a persistent lxde-pi desktop environment:

```
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=lightdm-xsession
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=lightdm-xsession
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDMSESSION=lightdm-xsession

** Message: 14:40:24.181: main.vala:101: Session is LXDE-pi
** Message: 14:40:24.182: main.vala:102: DE is LXDE
** Message: 14:40:24.341: main.vala:133: log directory: /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi
** Message: 14:40:24.341: main.vala:134: log path: /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/run.log
```

Let me know if there are other places I should look.

Historical Perspective

I have three Pi4s that run webcams. One is at my home in Northeast Thailand the other two are at a condo southwest of Bangkok. All are headless. All have RealVNC enabled via raspy-config. The two at the condo are behind a double NAT, so I have a remote (reverse) SSH tunnel set up from them to my desktop Mac at home. Nearly all of the work I do on these three Pi4s is via SSH. I generally have no need for a GUI.

This past December I decided that I wanted to clone the boot SD card for all three Pi4s. For the one at home I logged in via VNC and ran SD Card Copier (piclone) via the GUI. It worked fine.

Then I tried logging in via VNC to the two remote Pi4s. One worked fine and I was able to start SD Card Copier. But on the other Pi all I got via VNC was a blue desktop with no menu bar and no desktop icons. I discovered by accident that if I two-finger tapped on the desktop (a right-click) a hierarchical menu appeared. But, almost none of the software on that menu (including SD Card Copier) would actually run.

Then I set out trying to find out how to get the normal, default Buster desktop on the errant machine.

It took me many months of posting questions and inquiries and a bunch of personal research for me to finally find out that I could get the desktop by running startlxde-pi from a terminal session via VNC. This is all stuff that I know nothing about, so it has been a hard, frustrating slog.

Note that on the errant machine I eventually cloned the SD card using a command-line version of piclone, which worked just fine.

At this point (08 May 2022) I still don't understand why one of the three Pi4s is different from the other two.

Comment: @Milliways - What happened to your comment?

Comment: I apologised for misreading your question and after a few hours deleted the answer which was about Bullseye. (Novel writers are recommended to use character names which start with a different letter. OS authors should do the same!)

Comment: Quick guess is it's because there's no one logged in.  A desktop session is always opened by a user, for a user.  If no such normal user logs in, there's no active desktop session, if it boots to GUI, that GUI is a login screen, aka the "display manager" (DM) which is a separate entity from the desktop environment (DE, which is the de in lxde).   You need to enable autologin for the user you want to connect as, then there will already be a desktop open.

Comment: @goldilocks -In my original question I state that I have selected "B4 Desktop Autologin Desktop GUI, automatically logged" in raspy-config. Isn't that what you're saying I should do?

Comment: I tried this on a different Pi4 running Buster and selected:  B3 Desktop - Desktop GUI, requiring user to login. I had to log in, but the desktop showed up as soon as I did.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the `[selected]` in the output (which to nitpick is not really "I stated that").  So I'm wrong, you want the login.  Is this solved then, or is the problem now is that "it works on another Pi 4 but not this one?" :/

Comment: It works on two other Pies, but not this one. On this one I still have to open a terminal session (via VNC) and enter startlxde-pi & to get the desktop environment running. On my other two Pi 4s it starts without having to run startlxde-pi &.

Comment: OK. This is now semi-fixed. On the errant Pi I found this file: /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf. I think that file shouldn't be there if you're  logging in to the desktop. I removed that file. Now, on the errant Pi if I choose automatically logged on to the desktop (B4), the desktop starts automatically. If I chose user must log in (B3) I still need to start the desktop manually after logging in. On the other two Pi 4s, the desktop starts automatically if I choose B3 or B4. Neither of them have:  /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf

Comment: I added some historical perspective at the end of the OP. I know no one will actually read it, but it helped me to type it out.